# Asterisk PBX detect if someone enters an incorrect password

Tags: security, asterisk, pbx

I have a simple asterisk pbx that runs great. I am able to make phone calls and things work great.

Anyways the probelm is that I see an increase in my network traffic because someone is trying to use my pbx. In other words I see:

[image]

That shows up when I run the commad "asterisk -rvvv"

I can see that someone is atempting a different password. What I do then is I block that IP address on my firewall and things start working great again. The problem is that on the next day I get a different attack with a different IP. How can I get a notification when someone makes several incorrect password atempts so that I can block that IP address automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly recommend Fail2Ban for this exactly job:

- http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fail2ban
- http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Asterisk

Comment: Fail2ban is no longer recommended for Asterisk. It's better to use the AMI and write some code that monitors for failed logins and then automatically add them to your firewall or iptables. http://forums.asterisk.org/viewtopic.php?p=159984

Comment: I'm of the opinion that partial protection is better than none.  Most people do not have the skills required to create an effective AMI monitoring tool.  F2B still catches a significant number of "script kid" brute-force attacks.

Is it The Silver Bullet?  No.  But it's better than nothing at all.

Comment: It's a false sense of security and been publically denounced by Asterisk developers.

Comment: Ok, so what tool do -you- recommend for those folks who don't have an AMI scripting background?